# Is it possible to get locked out of certain pantheons in Godmaster DLC by doing certain choices?

Tags: hollow-knight

So, in Hollow Knight, there are several branching decisions, where you can basically nullify your possibility to fight certain bosses, e.g.

> leaving Zote to die so you can't fight his dream version

or

> deciding to banish Grimm troupe, so you can't fight Nightmare King Grimm.

Now, Godmaster adds pantheons, where you can fight bosses in "boss rush" manner. But to unlock pantheon, you need to defeat all bosses from this pantheon in main game (e.g. you can't get third pantheon if you didn't killed Hive Knight).

So, question is - if I make some bosses unavailable due to my decisions, am I locked out of pantheons which have those bosses?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get locked out of accessing Pantheons depending on choices you make. If you do not save Zote, Grey Prince Zote will simply be absent from Pantheons where you would encounter him, and he will not be a requirement to access them. And Nightmare King Grimm will be available to fight whether you fought him or banished him.